# How to use SVN in npm to install modules?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, svn, npm-install

I try to install a module use npm and get this error:

```
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > svn checkout https://github.com/SteamDatabase/Protobufs/trunk protobufs && svn checkout https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/trunk/Resources/ProtobufGen protobuf_gen && svn checkout https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/trunk/Resources/SteamLanguage steam_language
```

Comment: do you have a svn link in your package.json?

Comment: I'm a newbie. You can show how it should look?

Comment: A word of advice. Firstly please never copy a picture of the screen with code. Instead try to copy paste a representative example (called reprex) of the code. A `reprex` is the shortest possible code that replicates the problem. Remove all drills and focus on the problem lines.

Comment: Some one know what i nead to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to install those modules with Subversion? The native format in Github is git (svn is just a wrapper) and you only need an svn checkout if you're planning to contribute to the library, something unusual in general but even more for a library hosted in Github, and even then having your source code inside `node_modules` is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM is not really compatible with SVN, but there is a way to make it work. You can use the npm package `npm-svn`.

to add SVN dependencies you should have something like this in your `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "npm-svn": "latest"
},
"svnDependencies": {
  "svn-module": "svn://path/to/svn/repo",
  "svn-module@tag": "svn://path/to/svn/repo",
  "svn-module@tag|revision": "svn://path/to/svn/repo",
}
```

Check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-svn) for more information